# Multiple inheritance with Dart and accessing public variables from multiple levels up

Tags: dart

I've been working with Dart for a few weeks now, and so far so good.  I've run into a problem, however, when trying to access variables from a class that's a few levels higher.  I'm not sure how best to explain this without an actual sample, so here's a quick example:

http://pastebin.com/r2ru6G2w

To put this as simply as possible:

- AClass has a variable named "parameter."
- BClass inherits from AClass, also has a constructor parameter (incomingParameter) that is assigned to the "parameter" variable from AClass.
- CClass inherits from BClass, also has a constructor parameter (incomingParameter) that is simply passed on to BClass via the super initializer.
- DClass inherits from CClass, but does not have any constructor parameter.  Instead, I'm trying to pass the "parameter" variables all the way from AClass into the super initializer.

This results in an error, that says "Only static members can be accessed in initializers."  Fair enough.  Any idea how to get around this?

Thanks for all the help,
MR

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to do in DClass. You are trying to get the reference of an attribute in a class that has not been initialized. Could you describe what you want to do ? It looks like you want to have `DClass():super(null)`.

Comment: You try to pass a field that isn't initialized. What do you actually want to do? You've got to pass some value as that will get assigned to `parameter`. What your code tries to do is to assign the not initialized field `parameter` to itself. If you want to access `parameter` you can do so in the body of the constructor like in `BClass`.